# Showing that the limit is a tail event.

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

I'm stuck at trying to prove that some event is a tail event.

**Problem:**
Let $(X_{n})_{n\geq 1}$ be a sequence of random variables.
Prove that $$\left\{\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{X_{1}+X_{2}+\dots+X_{n}}{n} \text{ exists}\right\}$$ is in the tail $\sigma$-algebra.

**My attempt:**

Let $\mathcal{T} := \bigcap \sigma(X_{n},X_{n+1},...)$. Now, since $$\left\{\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{X_{1}+X_{2}+\dots+X_{n}}{n} \text{ exists}\right\}$$
is defined for $n>1$ then for some $k>1$ $$\left\{\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{X_{1}+X_{2}+\dots+X_{n}}{n} \text{ exists}\right\}$$ belongs to some sigma algebra $\sigma(X_{k},X_{k+1},\dots)$. Then that event is in fact in $\bigcap_{n} \sigma(X_{n},X_{n+1},\dots)$.

So, my question is, am I done now? I did it right?

Any suggestions will be really appreciated <3

Thanks so much

Comment: Your attempt is mere handwaving, can you be more formal ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It suffices to prove the equality $\left(\frac 1n \sum_{k=1}^n X_k \text{ converges}\right)=\left(\frac 1n \sum_{k=k_0}^n X_k \text{ converges}\right)$ for any $k_0\geq 1$.

Since $$\frac 1n \sum_{k=k_0}^n X_k(w) = \frac 1n \sum_{k=1}^n X_k(w) -\underbrace{\frac 1n \sum_{k=1}^{k_0-1} X_k(w)}_{\to 0} $$
$\frac 1n \sum_{k=k_0}^n X_k(w)$ converges iff $\frac 1n \sum_{k=1}^n X_k(w)$ converges. This proves the equality of events.

Hence $\left(\frac 1n \sum_{k=1}^n X_k \text{ converges}\right)\in \mathcal F^\infty_{k_0}$ for any $k_0$.